How to improve my classifier?
I'm training a non-linear classifier on a multilevel classification task. I prepare training data as a mapping of integer (x1, x2) coordinates to an integer ranging from zero to three. For every x1/x2 coordinate pair, I generate 5000 training samples with some added Gaussian noise. I train on a five layer classifier with 10 neurons in each hidden layer:
class ClassifierFiveHiddenLayer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_inputs, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, n_outputs):
        super().__init__()
        self.act_fn = nn.Tanh()
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(num_inputs, h1)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(h1, h2)
        self.linear3 = nn.Linear(h2, h3)
        self.linear4 = nn.Linear(h3, h4)
        self.linear5 = nn.Linear(h4, h5)
        self.linear6 = nn.Linear(h5, n_outputs)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.linear1(x)
        x = self.act_fn(x)
        x = self.linear2(x)
        x = self.act_fn(x)
        x = self.linear3(x)
        x = self.act_fn(x)
        x = self.linear4(x)
        x = self.act_fn(x)
        x = self.linear5(x)
        x = self.act_fn(x)
        x = self.linear6(x)
        return x  

The test result however looks a bit off, in the sense that it's not really able to classify test data:

The non-linear mapping is:
xy_mapping = {
    (0, 0): 0,
    (0, 1): 0,
    (0, 2): 1,
    (0, 3): 2,
    (1, 0): 1,
    (1, 1): 0,
    (1, 2): 2,
    (1, 3): 2,
    (2, 0): 3,
    (2, 1): 3,
    (2, 2): 2,
    (2, 3): 2,
    (3, 0): 3,
    (3, 1): 2,
    (3, 2): 3,
    (3, 3): 0
}

Not entirely sure how to improve this. Does it need more layers? Wider layers? More training data points?
As a control, a normal XOR classification seems to work:

